# Turn off "Step into:.." Immediate Window in VisualStudio while debugging

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Ever since VS2010 when I step through code using F8 I get uncessary text in the debuger that I did not get in VS2008. All I want to see is the results, not the "Step into:.." I tried setting different options in the debugger settings but nothing seemed to work.

For example:

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To 2
     Debug.Print(i)
 Next
```

Immediate Window when using the F8 key currently:

```
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print'
0
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print'
1
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print'
2
```

It used to show just results when using the F8 key:

```
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `Options` -> `Debugging` -> `Output Window` -> `General Output Settings` -> `Step Filtering Messages`.
It's turned on by default.

Comment: It seems to be turned off already, but still getting the "Step into..." text. Any other ideas?

Comment: umm... maybe try to disable the output->intermediate redirection?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right area. I got it. I also turned off the first option in the General Output Settings -> All debug output. Now I just get the results. Back to good.